# android studio 3.5: can I export run configuration to jar?

Tags: java, android-studio, executable-jar

In Ecliplse we could export executable jar from any class with static main() method. I've made a lot of utilities that way, using main app engine in-place.
But in Android Studio 3.5 I didn't found an easy way to do the same. Does it exist?
As a temporary solution I use Application target (in Run configurations) and it works the same, but how to export it as jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible you can just go to File -> New -> New Module

then select Java Library, choose a name and hit finish.

Then you will see a new Module in your Project View.

You can then go to your Gradle View and go under **YOUR NEW CREATED MODULE** -> Tasks -> build and then just double click on build.

Then it should have generated a .jar file which you can easily search in Windows Explorer for just go to your Project Path \ **YOUR NEW CREATED MODULE** \ build\libs